# Static and external path for Tomcat logs embeded

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, jhipster, maven-tomcat-plugin

As I can set up my tomcat embedded so that logs the write in a (external) specific route because if you do not lose every time I generate a new jar.

It is an application with Spring Boot and Jhipster

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I do not see any file where I can configure this route.
Jhipster 3.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Version 3.7, JHipster switched from Tomcat to Undertow, so you shouldn't do tomcat specific stuff, if you want to stay flexible to further updates.

for your logging problem, it might worth for you to take a look at [JHipsters monitoring solution](https://jhipster.github.io/monitoring/), which uses the ELK stack. So you route your logs to a tool, which offers great options to analyze logs.

**edit**: Otherwise the log routing is done using Logback, which is shipped with JHipster. The file(s) you are looking for is logback.xml

Comment: The version of Jhipster is 3.4.2

Comment: anyways I would recommend to use JHipster Console for logging. Otherwise the log routing is done using Logback, which is shipped with JHipster. The file(s) you are looking for is logback.xml